# How to avoid small jerk in view while Calling setSelection() after scrolling in onScrollStateChanged() method?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, scroll

when i am calling setSelection() after scrolling in onScrollStateChanged() Method, it gets vibrate or small jerk or something jump is happening in the listView. Now i am passing index to setSelection() which is first visible item index in the listview after scrolling,but i am not passing last index or any other index which is far away visible items in the listView after scrolling.

Any idea or suggestion how to slow the view or avoid that small jerk while showing that particular item in setSelection()..or how to manage the speed of the view according to scrolling motion.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `smoothScrollToPosition(position)` instead. [Android ref](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#smoothScrollToPosition(int)).

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got answer what i was really need in my app based on smoothScrollBy(), by passing height of the first child element and duration in milliseconds.

By Doing the below 3 Steps:

1.Initialize the two variable for scrolling up and down:

```
int scrollingUp=0,scrollingDown=0;
```

2.Then increment the value of the variable based on scrolling:

```
 @Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
    int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

    if(mLastFirstVisibleItem<firstVisibleItem)
            {
                scrollingDown=1;
            }
            if(mLastFirstVisibleItem>firstVisibleItem)
            {
                scrollingUp=1;
            }
            mLastFirstVisibleItem=firstVisibleItem;
}
```

3.Then do the changes in the onScrollStateChanged():

```
@Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        switch (scrollState) {
        case SCROLL_STATE_IDLE:

            if(scrollingUp==1)
            {
                mainListView.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        View child = mainListView.getChildAt (0);    // first visible child
                        Rect r = new Rect (0, 0, child.getWidth(), child.getHeight());     // set this initially, as required by the docs
                        double height = child.getHeight () * 1.0;
                        mainListView.getChildVisibleRect (child, r, null);
                        int dpDistance=Math.abs (r.height());
                        double minusDistance=dpDistance-height;
                        if (Math.abs (r.height()) < height/2)
                        {
                            mainListView.smoothScrollBy(dpDistance, 1500);
                        }       
                        else
                        {
                            mainListView.smoothScrollBy((int)minusDistance, 1500);
                        }
                        scrollingUp=0;

                    }
                });
            }
            if(scrollingDown==1)
            {
                mainListView.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        View child = mainListView.getChildAt (0);    // first visible child
                        Rect r = new Rect (0, 0, child.getWidth(), child.getHeight());     // set this initially, as required by the docs
                        double height = child.getHeight () * 1.0;
                        mainListView.getChildVisibleRect (child, r, null);
                        int dpDistance=Math.abs (r.height());
                        double minusDistance=dpDistance-height;
                        if (Math.abs (r.height()) < height/2)
                        {
                            mainListView.smoothScrollBy(dpDistance, 1500);
                        }       
                        else
                        {
                            mainListView.smoothScrollBy((int)minusDistance, 1500);
                        }
                        scrollingDown=0;
                    } 
                });
            }
        break;
        case SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL:

            break;
            }
        }
```